# How to configure a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I configure a Ruby ​​on Rails application to switch between production and test environments? Is there any way?

Comment: so you want to change between `test` and `production` while the server is running, without restarting?

Comment: So I wanted the administrator to click on a button that would change the status of the production environment to test, regardless of whether or not it restarts the server

Comment: Does the administrator have access to the server? Would he be able to restart the server with changed ENV variables?

Comment: The administrator does not have access to the server, but could restart the server with changed ENV variables!

Comment: I'm going to upvote this. The real idea behind the question is how to store configuration settings that can be toggled/switched at run-time. Think about how Wordpress, Drupal and other sites use settings/configuration that are stored within the database so you can toggle settings at run-time. You cannot switch between test and production environments; but you can build models/controllers to switch between site A and site B configuration settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create environment-specific configuration files in the `config/` directory and in `db/`.

To switch between the different environments, you can specify the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable when you run rails:

```
rails s RAILS_ENV=production
rails s RAILS_ENV=test
# With bundler
bundle exec rails s RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rails s RAILS_ENV=test
```

[You can read more about it in the Configuration Rails Applications guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings)

If you're looking to set up multiple configurations for your site, then you will want to create a settings model in your database. This will enable you to switch between site configurations. You should not rely on the production/test/staging configuration YAML files, you should instead treat your web app as multi-site; different configuration settings stored for each site/domain/subdomain, similar to how it's done for Wordpress, Drupal, Magento and other web apps based on those CMSes.

Comment: and if it was a button as the user clicked, did it change the state of the server, is there such a possibility?

Comment: @GiovaniCarvalho not sure what that has to do with changing the environment that the server is running in

Comment: So I wanted the administrator to click on a button that would change the status of the production environment to test, regardless of whether or not it restarts the server

Comment: that's not possible; what you can do however is to create new configuration files (config/whatever.yml and config/hello.yml) and switch between those, you will need custom code that drops database connections and busts cache when the config changes. The best way to do this is to store your site-specific config in the database. Think about how Wordpress works, they store config inside the database so you can switch your site's configuration at run-time without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a near impossibility because you might be using a different configuration for your machine in production vs testing. For instance you might be using puma or unicorn in production while you are just using rails s in testing. Also, you are probably using a different database in production vs testing.

I don't know what your use case is but my recommendation would be to create a button that redirects the user to a different server when they click this button. The only other possibility is to make this button trigger a new deploy whenever it is clicked. So basically, 5 minutes after you click this button, you'll have a testing server deployed in the place of your production server. Your load balancer will point to this new server compared to the old server.  This is incredible complicated and the use case probably doesn't exist but it actually answers your question.  Good luck!